# Error executing a test with SpecFlow newer version

Tags: specflow

I have setup a new testing instance using SpecFlow 3.9.40 with C# and NUnit. This in Visual Studio 2022 and using built-in SpecFlow to create project, so all necessary packages are pulled in. There are no build errors, but test execution is failing with following message:

OneTimeSetUp: System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void BoDi.ObjectContainer.RegisterTypeAs(System.String

This message is pointing to an auto generated class, see image.

I'm not sure how to fix this error and hoping someone that has upgraded to SpecFlow 3.9.40 can give me some pointers. I have SpecFlow 3.0225 working fine, no such error. I really would like to upgrade SpecFlow to take advantage of newer developments. Thank you.

Comment: Try updating NuGet packages that generate the feature.cs files.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Everything is up to latest package. Letting SpecFlow plugin create the project lets it handle necessary packages. Do you know a specific package that could cause error?

Comment: Please list the NuGet packages you have installed in your test project.

Comment: Greg I have managed to get it running, removed all previous references to classes I had imported and resolved references using the new packages. That seems to have been my issue. I appreciate you following up. Thanks.